# kendo MultiSelectBox with Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, multi-select

My project requires a MultiSelectBox.

I have found an addon build on KendoUI DropDownList widget here:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/multi-select-with-checkboxes-plugin

I have changed the code to work with KendoUI version 2015.1.429.

(I believe it works with later versions, too.)

Please see my code:
http://dojo.telerik.com/@DUKEiLL/OziqE

How can I add a filter option to this addon so it works properly?

Thank you,

Daniel.

Comment: You may want to implement and bind a kendo.data.DataSource() and then manage your filter on the dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an extra option for filtering.

```
 options: {
        name: "MultiSelectBox",
        index: -1,
        showSelectAll: null,
        autoClose: false,
        preSummaryCount: 1,  // number of items to show before summarising
        emptySelectionLabel: null,  // what to show when no items are selected
        selectionChanged: null, // provide callback to invoke when selection has changed
        allText: "All", // select All text 
        filter: "contains"
    },
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/emebO

The filter: option can accept different types of filter such as "startswith", "endswith" and "contains"

Comment: I have already tried to apply filter settings.
However, it does **not work properly!**  
For example, using the filter causes the "Select All" option to disappear.